# Flags in unity keyboard indicator

Tags: 11.04, unity, keyboard, indicator, icons

I would like to apply [Language Flags for Faenza and Elementary](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=133726) to Unity keyboard indicator. But old "hack" doesn't seem to work on it. Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, just log out, in needed. Everything works.